# Why is Jsoup returning an empty string when I try to scrape this data?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
public class JSoupBundesliga {
    
    private static final String URL = "https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2019-2020/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Document doc = null;
        
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(6000).get();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        Elements awayScore = doc.getElementsByClass(".leagues--static event--leagues summary-results");
        System.out.println(awayScore);
        
    }

}
```

Above is my full code, the website looks like this:

[Link To Inspect Element Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykULy.png)

I am trying to scrape the part I highlighted in blue, but I can't scrape anything. So, if someone could even help with the names like "Arsenal" that would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

That page URL cannot be scraped like this. The actual HTML content is very barebones; instead, everything you see in the webbrowser when you access it is filled in by javascript.

JSoup isn't a javascript runner and isn't a browser. It simply loads the HTML you want, **does not run javascript, and cannot be made to do so**, and will then let you scrape whatever you wanna scrape. Which, in this case, is basically nothing - as the HTML served up by that site doesn't contain anything useful.

Many websites online work like this: All actual content is written in by javascript.

You're stuck in a dead end: JSoup cannot be used here. What you can attempt to do is selenium or similar tools: These start a real browser and really use it to render the page just like real browsers do, and then lets you programmatically interact with the DOM similar to JSoup. Getting it to run on headless servers can be lightly challenging, and it's incredibly heavy (JSoup can trivially run in tiny memory footprints and very very quickly. This selenium route very much cannot - it needs to fire up an entire browser which are relatively speaking humongous beasts, of course). Selenium isn't meant for this purpose - it's meant for testing your own websites. But it can do the job, more or less.

Many browsers have a 'disable javascript' option, possibly in the devtools. Turn that on, load the page. What you see is what you can scrape with JSoup. If the content you want disappears when you do this, then **You cannot scrape it with JSoup**.

Comment: Hi rzwitserloot! I disabled javascript in flashscore and can still see this class name, yet my program won't run. Any other possible reason for this?